# Liebig's law of minimum

Tags: homework, ecology

I was reading from **Odum** about **Liebig's law of minimum**.

It said that

> the law is appicable in steady state condition i.e. when the inflow of energy and material balances out the outflow.

I got two questions:

**1**.Here what is actually in steady state? Photosynthesis? or Plant community? or Biotic community?

**2**. Inflow of energy and material balances out the outflow.

What is the net material/energy that is flowing in an out of a system? Could it be amount of light absorbed and amount of glucose and O2 produced respectively? He used the word balances which means they are not equal actually but proportionate I suppose.

Comment: Your second question isn't a question. Please reformulate as a question.

Comment: The question is beneath the statement that is numbered 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not directly related to Liebig's Law of the Minimum. Instead you ask about a conditions under which the Law holds according to your quote.

From the quote it is clear what is in steady state: it is the total amount of energy and material. If the the amount of energy and material flowing into a system equals ("balances out") the amount of energy and material leaving the system, the total amount in the system does not change, that is, it is in steady state.

This does not mean that other quantities in the system are necessarily in steady state. For instance, the species composition of a bacterial community may fluctuate or evolution may cause the community to change.

An example of the sort of systems we are talking about here is the [chemostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemostat). A chemostat is a device for culturing microorganisms. It consists of a culture vessel connected to a feed bottle. A solution of nutrients (the growth medium) literally flows from the feed into the chemostat. Microorganisms in the chemostat will grow and reproduce (if the concentration of nutrients is sufficient). A mixture of microorganisms, unused nutrients, and byproducts of growth leaves the chemostat in the effluent flowing out of the outflow of the vessel. The rate at which this happens is the same as the rate at which medium flows into the vessel. Typically, after a while the concentration of microorganisms and the concentration of nutrients in the chemostat and effluent do not change anymore (if the inflow is constant, that is). The chemical conditions in the chemostat have then become static (hence "chemostat"). The concentration of nutrients and microorganisms are then at steady state.

In the case that the microorganisms are [phototrophic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototroph), the nutrients may be inorganic and energy is added to the system through light. The light absorbed may then be considered as the energy flowing in, and the energy flowing out is then the chemical bond energy in the organic material that make up the microorganisms and the byproducts, and heat.

Chemostats are culturing devices, but are also models of natural systems such as lakes or ecosystems.

Liebig's Law of the Minimum says whichever resource (nutrient of light) is in short supply determines the growth rate of an organism. For instance, if nutrient concentrations are in ample supply but light levels are low, changing the nutrient concentrations will not change the growth rate of the organisms, however, changing the light levels will. The quote of Odum suggests the Law only holds under steady state conditions, but I do not understand very well why this would be so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have time to read it now. I'll let you know if I have follow up questions in a few days.